# Is it possible to scroll a ListView in and out of the frame?

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a Activity with a layout which only displays a Listview. The view is long so you can scroll it. I have searched a while now but didn´t find anything. Is there a tool so you can scroll a List out of a Layout. Meaning that when you are at the buttom or to of the list and scroll into the direction where the list ends that the list dissapears at the button or top of the layout and you see the backround. Has anyone done this before?

Comment: Something like this? https://medium.com/ribot-labs/exploring-the-new-android-design-support-library-b7cda56d2c32

Comment: I think add a pair of margin and padding like margintop="-50dp" paddingTop="50dp" to the list view may solve your problem. Also overscroll property can do a similar effect

Comment: @MicheleLacorte is there a reason my android Studio doesn´t know snackbar?

Comment: Yes..import design support library and try..it shuld work!

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It can be done but there need to be some elements before or after the list view.
Thus there will be a relative layout inside which there will be a list view and a textView.

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />
    <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnButton"
            android:text="Hello"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

In such a case where there are many elements above and below a listView you will be able to scroll out of the listView frame.

Comment: How would you be able to scroll the list out of the layout there?